# jboss-as-maven-plugin Failed to getClass for org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.Deploy

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I'm trying tu use jboss-as-maven-plugin at pre(and post)-integration-test phase to deploy (and undeploy) my test webapp and when mvn install is executed, the (un-)deployment does not happen. The following Jenkins job's output seems to point me to configuration but I can't figure out whats's missing :

**maven output :**

```
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2(default-jar)
forkedProjectSucceeded com.hck.debate:debate-test:2.1.15-SNAPSHOT
Dec 3, 2012 11:28:19 PM hudson.maven.ExecutedMojo <init>
WARNING: Failed to getClass for org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.Deploy
mojoStarted org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final(set-env)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final:deploy (set-env) @ debate-test ---
Dec 3, 2012 11:28:20 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 3, 2012 11:28:20 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 3, 2012 11:28:20 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.7.GA
mojoSucceeded org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final(set-env)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12.4(default)
```

**maven output in debug mode (mvn -X install) :**

```
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2(default-jar)
forkedProjectSucceeded com.hck.debate:debate-test:2.1.16-SNAPSHOT
Dec 4, 2012 6:00:45 PM hudson.maven.ExecutedMojo <init>
WARNING: Failed to getClass for org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.Deploy
mojoStarted org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final(set-env)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final:deploy (set-env) @ debate-test ---

[DEBUG] org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:jar:7.2.Final:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile
[DEBUG]                org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.8:compile
[DEBUG]    org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.8:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jboss.as:jboss-as-cli:jar:7.1.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss:staxmapper:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.remoting3:jboss-remoting:jar:3.2.7.GA:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.0.3.GA:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller:jar:7.1.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.modules:jboss-modules:jar:1.1.2.GA:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.msc:jboss-msc:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:jar:1.0.3.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager:jar:1.3.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-processor:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]             system:jdk-tools:jar:jdk:system
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:1.3.14.GA:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:1.3.14.GA:compile
[DEBUG]          org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.0.3.GA:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.1.0.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk:system
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.as:jboss-as-build-config:jar:7.1.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client:jar:7.1.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.as:jboss-as-protocol:jar:7.1.2.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss:jboss-dmr:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.0.0.GA:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.1:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:jar:7.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.as:jboss-as-cli:jar:7.1.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: jline:jline:jar:0.9.94
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss:staxmapper:jar:1.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.sasl:jboss-sasl:jar:1.0.1.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.remoting3:jboss-remoting:jar:3.2.7.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:jar:3.0.3.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller:jar:7.1.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.modules:jboss-modules:jar:1.1.2.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.msc:jboss-msc:jar:1.0.2.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.remotingjmx:remoting-jmx:jar:1.0.3.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.logmanager:jboss-logmanager:jar:1.3.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-processor:jar:1.0.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: system:jdk-tools:jar:jdk
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling:jar:1.3.14.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-river:jar:1.3.14.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:jar:3.0.3.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss:jboss-vfs:jar:3.1.0.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: sun.jdk:jconsole:jar:jdk
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.as:jboss-as-build-config:jar:7.1.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client:jar:7.1.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.as:jboss-as-protocol:jar:7.1.2.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss:jboss-dmr:jar:1.1.1.Final
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jboss.threads:jboss-threads:jar:2.0.0.GA
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.8
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@cac268]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) checkPackaging = true
[DEBUG]   (f) force = true
[DEBUG]   (f) hostname = 10.10.101.84
[DEBUG]   (f) port = 9999
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.hck.debate:debate-test:2.1.16-SNAPSHOT @ /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/sauce-dev/workspace/debate-test/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) targetDir = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/sauce-dev/workspace/debate-test/target
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
Dec 4, 2012 6:00:46 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 4, 2012 6:00:46 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
Dec 4, 2012 6:00:46 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.7.GA

[DEBUG] Executing deployment
mojoSucceeded org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.2.Final(set-env)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.12.4(default)
```

**my pom file :**

```
    <build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>10.10.101.84</hostname>
        <port>9999</port>
    </configuration>
    <executions>        
        <execution>     
            <id>set-env</id>        
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>     
            <id>unset-env</id>      
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>undeploy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
        <plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any clues?

**Edit** : I think I have a bigger issue here as jboss-as-maven-plugin execution is done in the test module (the pom file above is the test modules's one) so it tries to deploy the test module jar (and I want to deploy the war which is another module)...

Comment: Can you run it with debug enabled? `mvn -X test`

Comment: Thanks for looking. I edited the question with the output for `mvn -X install`

Comment: I find this line `WARNING: Failed to getClass for org.jboss.as.plugin.deployment.Deploy` odd. A quick Google search shows this in various Jenkins build logs. Though it does look like the plugin is doing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to deploy the test module jar not the war (which is another module). Thanks to @James R. Perkins who helped me open my eyes